# Redirecting to another page. How do I display a countdown?

Tags: codeigniter

I'm just wondering if the following is possible:
I don't know anything about JQuery and I don't know how to make my own javascripts yet.
When a user logs into my website, they'll get a page that says "login completed".
Under that sentence, I would like to get a sentence that counts down the seconds until they are redirected. Is there a simple way to do this?

I already have a countdown function:
When the function is first called, the view 'view_login_success' is loaded and the $data[] array is passed to it. $data['sec'] holds the seconds remaining that should be printed on the screen.
When the do-while loop is over, the user should be redirected to the homepage.
What happends is, the 'view_login_success'-view isn't loaded at all and after 5 seconds, the user is redirected to the homepage.

```
function timerIn() {
    $now = time();
    $this->load->view('view_login_success', $this->data);
    do {
        if (time() - $now != 0) {
            $this->data['sec'] = $this->data['sec'] - 1;
            $this->load->view('view_login_success', $this->data);
            $now = time();
        }
    } while ($this->data['sec'] != 1);
    $this->data['sec'] = 5;
    redirect('user/start');
}
```

Here is the view:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Login geslaagd</title>
    <?php $this->load->view('templates/header2'); ?>
</head>
<body>
        <h2  style="text-align: center;"><?php echo strtoupper(substr($this->session->userdata('gebruikersnaam'),0,1));
        echo substr($this->session->userdata('gebruikersnaam'),1); ?>, U bent ingelogd!</h2>
        <p>U word doorverwezen: <?php echo $sec; ?> seconden...</p>
</body>
<?php $this->load->view('templates/footer'); ?>
```

If there's a way to do this in JQuery of Javascript, then please explain to me what I should do to get it to work.
Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not how php works.

If you want the page to redirect after 5 secs you have to do so in the JS code.
You redirect the user without sending the view to the client.

Right now you are only waiting 5 seconds to redirect. So:

- Show the view
- The JS will have the timer and then redirects.

The javascript code would be something like this:

```
setTimeout(function(){
  window.location.href = 'theURLyouwant';
},5000)
```

OR you could use the ol' meta tag

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5; URL=theURLyouwant">
```

Comment: can I use header method of PHP to do the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

Use code-igniter to solve this problem. Use this reference class output. Output class will be loaded automatically. You don't need to load this. Use this function to set header.

```
 $this->output->set_header('refresh:time-to-redirect; url='.site_url("your-url"));
```

[For more detail about this class.](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/output.html)